# How can I add sharp edges at the end of semicircle's vertices?

Tags: mesh, edges, subdivision-surface

blender beginner here. I'm modelling a cap, and after doing a semicircle shaped hole, I couldn't find a way to make the lower corners of the hole sharp looking. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems to work fine, with almost no pinching:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me!